# IntelliJ IDEA - unix python virtualenv on WIndows

Tags: python, windows-7, intellij-idea, virtualenv, python-2.6

I have Python application and virtualenv for it. I run it on Debian virtual machine. Is it possible to configure IntelliJ to start application and use IntelliJ debug tools? The problem is how to use virtualenv for debian in Windows 7 system.

Comment: intelij or pycharm? if its pycharm it allows you to create a venv inside the ide.

Comment: intellij with python plugin

Comment: any raeson for that? do you use jython?

Comment: sorry i didn't mention i am not sure if you are aware. the company who made intelij also has an ide for python called pycharm.

Comment: Yes, i know about this, but it dont solve this problem. And it require new licence.

Answer (score 0):

Just install an appropriate python and virtualenv for that python directly on the windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. If connect with my virtual machine by remote debug tool. I add one line with IntellJ/PyCharm generate to entry point of paster script. Before debug i run script (using IntelliJ remote tool) with run application on virtual machine.